# Word for extending the period of allowed submission in economic context

Tags: word-choice, word-request

There's a law that each financial institution must report the holdings to the government every month. Consequently, the period commences on December 1st and closes on December 31st (for the current month, that is).

On occasion (which apparently is frequently), some institutions screw up and don't deliver on time (it's only our money and federal law, right?) so we had to introduce a possibility extend the period and allow the buggers to submit the data a bit later.

What should such a period be called. Extra bonus if the term is technical and not commonly known.

Naturally, *extended* came up but it's not correct because technically speaking we can't extend jack. The law is the law. I need an adjective that corresponds to the dead-line being later than originally expected.

Another term would be [*respited*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/respited) but that creates an aura of not needing to do any work during the extra time.

Comment: It is commonly called a "grace period". For example, holdings must be reported within the *n*-day grace period following the filing deadline.

Comment: Though I don't know why you'd want to award a bonus if the term is technical and not commonly known.  Communication is not about finding recondite language that nobody understands.

Comment: @TRomano It's not about communicating with people. I'm designing a class in a computer program. The dryer and less recognizable the term, the better. Because that way, people won't have an emotion based prejudice about its meaning. Can you suggest a formal term for *grace period*, too?

Comment: **Grace period** is formal enough to be used in legal contracts.

Comment: @TRomano Thanks, mate! That's great. If I'd like to adjectivize the term (with **no** consideration for readability what so ever) - would it be *grace**d** period* or *grace period**ed***? In the table, it's not the grace period that's listed. It's rather a marker for when a file reading has got more time allotment and is extended (graced perioded'ish).

Comment: Sorry, questions about unnatural, unidiomatic uses (e.g. variable naming ) are off-topic on ELL.  A natural idiomatic question would be "Is it in the grace period?", to which the answer would be Yes or No. So you could name a property **inGracePeriod** and make it a boolean.  In other words, use a prepositional phrase rather than an attributive adjective, and applying the conventions of "headlinese/telegraphese", drop the article.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I currently have a six month visa with a **grace period** of fourteen days. That means that my visa will expire six months after my arrival and it's technically an offence to stay longer, but if I leave the country within fourteen days of the expiry date, I don't have to pay any penalty.

Similarly, in India, employers have to make payment to the [Employer's Provident Fund](https://tgassociates.nowfloats.com/Provident-Fund-Payment-of-contribution-by-the-employers-Removing-of-grace-period-of-5-days-Dear-all-The-employers-were-previously-allowed-a-grace-period-of-five-days-to-remit-the-contributions-as-the-system-of-calculation-of-wag/b7) by the 15th of the month. Employers were allowed a **grace period** of five days to arrange the payment, but now that most employers submit their payments electronically, the grace period has been cancelled.

If you want an adjective meaning "submission deadline extended", then **stayed** is perfect. [stay](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/stay) means **Stop, delay, or prevent (something), in particular suspend or postpone (judicial proceedings) or refrain from pressing (charges):**

Comment: That's **precisely** the meaning I'm going for. Now, is there another term, equivalent to it, but more formal, economical etc.?

Comment: **grace period** is pretty formal. If you want to make it sound more obscure, you could call it a **stay**, in the sense **stay of execution**. If you want to make it neutral, you could call it an **extension**.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. Can you take a peek at the comment above (about adjectivization of the term)?

Comment: @KonradViltersten, answer updated